# creating table in access database as in excel and accessing by sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have created a form for searching customer in my application.when search button is clicked i want the payments details of respective customer  stored in the access to be displayed in gridview.i know the procedure to display the table into grid view.my question is
1.do i need to create 12 records as shown in picture for each customer?
2.how do i calculate balance automatically when amount field is entered.
picture
 http://s44.photobucket.com/user/amarn19/slideshow/

Comment: Can you just paste the picture here?

Comment: please click on the link given above.i cant upload picture here since my achievements is 2